# Cloud Functions internal traffic - does it include *bridged* perimeters?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Does "internal only" ingress for Cloud Functions include traffic originating from perimeters that are **bridged** to the perimeter holding the function?

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings) says that internal traffic must originate from the same perimeter as that which the Cloud Function resides in.  Just wondering whether in fact traffic coming from a bridged perimeter will be allowed, too.

Comment: I never tested, but I would like to say yes. A bridged perimeter is a part of the perimeter, so....

Comment: As per the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/share-across-perimeters#service_perimeter_bridges) perimeter bridges are bidirectional. For example, if project A and B is in the same perimeter, data can [move](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/share-across-perimeters#example_of_perimeter_bridges) between them.